# Optimization: Set or Subtract?

Tags: c#, optimization, xna

a very simple question here.

I'm coding a multi-player game in XNA, what would be a better option here - and why?

(Line 7 is the only changed line in each option)

Option 1:

```
const float SyncFrequency = (1 / 30f);
float Sync;

void Sync(GameTime GT)
{
    Sync += (float)GT.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
    if (Sync >= SyncFrequency) { Sync = 0; SyncAll(); }
}

void SyncAll() { /*Syncing Code Here*/ }
```

Option 2:

```
const float SyncFrequency = (1 / 30f);
float Sync;

void Sync(GameTime GT)
{
    Sync += (float)GT.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
    if (Sync >= SyncFrequency) { Sync -= SyncFrequency; SyncAll(); }
}

void SyncAll() { /*Syncing Code Here*/ }
```

Also:

Notice I use floats:

```
const float SyncFrequency = (1 / 30f);
```

Would using extra-precision be needed at all? E.g:

```
const double SyncFrequency = (1 / 30d);
```

Comment: Benchmark. But don't worry about micro-optimisations

Comment: I've done that, and you they're the same, measuring in ticks with a stopwatch, it's just.. I could swear I read some time ago about subtracting the frequency is better than setting to 0 somewhere before.

Comment: Well mathematically it makes sense, Example: if the frequency is 30 milliseconds, and every frame interval is 16.666ms (60fps), then after 2 frames it will reach 33.333. And then substracting 30ms, you're back down on 3.333ms (instead of 0, which you would be if you simply reset it). So over the course of several minutes, you'll have run more accurate updates than if you just rely on Update, and sets it to 0.

Comment: @BjarkeSøgaard thank you, I would mark that as the answer if you put it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathematically it makes sense to subtract instead of resetting.

Example: Standard 60fps means updating approximately every 16.666ms. If you have a network connection that you poll on every 30ms, upon the second Update, the time passed will have been 33.333ms, and this means that if you reset, you will be back at square one again. Whereas if you subtract 30ms from the current, you're down on 3.333ms. So over the course of a few seconds, you'll have run a more accurate amount of polls on the network connection.

It all depends on the situation really. In the above mentioned instance, you might run into situation where the application will poll the network connection 33 times, and other times it may do it 32, or 34 times, due to the time from the previous runs. All this can of course be calculated.

This may lead to uneven (probably unnoticeable, but still) gameplay, if it is actually used for network polling.

However for things such as Animating, it makes sense, since you'll most likely ALWAYS want the smoothest animating your hardware can deliver.

Especially for movement, since some PCs can't update 60 times per second (either because of hardware limitations, or the software simply only supports 30 or maybe 24fps). This will also lead to uneven movement, if you don't actually use the time passed (16.666ms in 60fps) to calculate movement and the likes.

**Rant ended**

Answer (score 0):

To further expand on Bjarke's great explanation, I coded this for my use, but feel free to use it:

```
public static class Timers
{
    private static Dictionary<string, Timer> Array;
    public static void Add(string Name, double Interval)
    {
        if (Array == null) Array = new Dictionary<string, Timer>();
        if (!Array.ContainsKey(Name)) Array.Add(Name, new Timer(Interval));
    }
    public static void Remove(string Name) { if ((Array != null) && Array.ContainsKey(Name)) Array.Remove(Name); }
    public static void Clear() { Array.Clear(); Array = null; }

    public static void Update(GameTime GameTime)
    {
        if (Array != null)
            foreach (Timer Timer in Array.Values)
            {
                if (Timer.Time >= Timer.Interval) Timer.Time -= Timer.Interval;
                Timer.Time += GameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
            }
    }
    public static bool Tick(string Name) { return ((Array != null) && Array.ContainsKey(Name) && (Array[Name].Time >= Array[Name].Interval)); }

    private class Timer
    {
        public double Interval, Time;

        public Timer(double Interval) { this.Interval = Interval; }
    }
}
```

---

To add a timer:

```
//Parameter 1: The name of the timer for your use.
//Parameter 2: The time (of interval) for each tick.
Timers.Add("Name of your timer!", (1 / 30d));
    // (1 / 30d) = 30 times a second
```

(add your timer in the load function of your game)

---

To use your timer:

In your game update method (at the start of it), call:

```
Timers.Update(gameTime);
```

Then you can use any timers that you've added like so:

```
if (Tick("Name of your timer!"))
{
    //Code here to execute on the tick of the timer
}
```